# “react-infinite-scroll-component” Stopped working after one call (loadMore only gets called once)

Tags: reactjs, pagination, infinite-scroll, react-infinite-scroll-component, react-pagination

I use the react-infinite-scroll-component library for pagination,but even though hasMore is true, loadMore is called once.

```
     <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={100}
      pullDownToRefreshThreshold={50}
      next={loadMoreConversation}
      scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
      hasMore={true}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
      <ChatItemList
        chatItems={chatItems}
        isInDeleteMode={deleteActive}
        onBottomDrawerHandler={onBottomDrawerHandler}
      />
    </InfiniteScroll>
```

Please help me with this, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had this issue. It turns out I was using dataLength in the wrong way. I thought it was supposed to be the total length of items that could be displayed, but instead, it seems it should be the length of items that are currently displayed, so the correct way is should be something like this:

```
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={page * 10}
      pullDownToRefreshThreshold={50}
      next={loadMoreConversation}
      scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
      hasMore={true}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
      <ChatItemList
        chatItems={chatItems}
        isInDeleteMode={deleteActive}
        onBottomDrawerHandler={onBottomDrawerHandler}
      />
    </InfiniteScroll>
```

in this case, I load 10 items per page. I hope this helps you because I searched a lot and did not find an answer until I reached it with all the effort and error.

Comment: They should totally mention that in the docs. I spent a frustrating our before stumbled upon your answer. 
Thank you!

Comment: is working! thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. This seems to be a common enough issue to warrant a special note in the docs

Comment: this is ridiculous, its so misleading. if I didnt search here I would never have achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a React Query `useInfiniteQuery()` example, assuming you have:

```
data: {
  pages: [
    {/*a page*/
      results:[
        {/*an item*/
          /*...*/
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Set your `dataLength` this way:

```
const {isSuccess, 
       isLoading, 
       isError, 
       data, 
       error, 
       hasNextPage, 
       fetchNextPage, 
       isFetchingNextPage
      } = useInfiniteQuery(
        path /*your query path here*/,
        fetchFn /*your fetch function here*/);
return <div>
    {isError && <div>Error! {error?.message}</div>}
    {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    {isSuccess && data?.pages && (
        <div>
            <ListHeader isFetching={isFetchingNextPage} data={data}/>
            <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={data.pages.reduce((acc, page) => acc + page.results.length, 0)}
                next={fetchNextPage}
                hasMore={hasNextPage}
                loader={<div>Loading...</div>}
                endMessage={<p>- You have seen it all -</p>}
            >
                {data.pages.map((page, i)=> (
                    <Fragment key={i+''}>
                    {page.results.map((item, j)=> (
                        <ListItem key={i+'.'+j} path={path} item={item}/>
                    ))}
                </Fragment>
                ))}
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    )}
</div>
```

Where ListHeader and ListItem are components of your own.